# error When installing Cumulative Update in SP2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, cumulative-update

I have SharePoint server 2013 with this 15.0.4569.1000
I have to install the cumulative update october 2015  to get this builversion. 15.0.4763.1000: 
So

1-

> I installed the   Service Pack 1 for Microsoft SharePoint Server 2013
>   (KB2880552) 64-Bit Edition 15.0.4571.1502

2-

> there is my issue : when i install the ​SharePoint Server 2013
>     KB3085492 I get an error :

```
OPatchInstall: Property 'PATCH.FILEID.EULA' value 'supplementaleula_sharepoint_fr-fr.txt'
OPatchInstall: Property 'PATCH.LANG' value '1036'
OPatchInstall: Property 'PATCH.RESULT.CANCELED' value '0'
OPatchInstall: Property 'PPSMAMUISP-EN-US' value 'NoShow'
```

SO I check the updates :an thats what I found :

[image: Server Build]

[![Updates Build][2]][2]

So my sharepoint cong couldn't upgrade after the SP1 martket 2 : the 15.0.4571.1502 biuild version

Any idea to force the upgrade of my sharepoint config ?

this is the log :

```
[opatch log][1]
```

Comment: Are u using English version of sharepoint or French? Are u have multiple language pack in the farm? What is base version language?

Comment: I am using french.

Comment: Are u using French version of cu as well?

Comment: Could you please share complete log file, I am sure there will be some other issue causing the error

Comment: yes i using all french version as well, i just installed the Language service Pack SP1 for Français , and i'am waiting the wizard  to finish , besides i wil share the log , thanks

Comment: most probably this will fix the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to the SharePoint SP1 is not inculde the update for language Pack,So 
I think that the main issue :

> you are not installed the Language service Pack SP1 for Français after
>   you installed SharePoint 2013 SP1 .

So try first to install the [Modules linguistiques pour SharePoint Server 2013 SP1 - [Français]](https://www.microsoft.com/fr-FR/download/details.aspx?id=42082)
 then install the CU OCT 2015